# Combining multiple results in Google Sheets using query

Tags: google-sheets

I am using query to display a list of top products that were sold in a date range. The date range is selected via drop downs. I also want to combine the results of the top products query for multiple months selected.
This is the result from my query.
[image: Current Results from Query with multiple months selected]

I want to combine all of the Items from each month that are the same, and show total SKU sales and Units sold total, for that product within the date range. It should look like this:
[image: ![here how should look]
I don't care about the months column here, I just want total products sold for each Item from the entire date range selected.

Here is my query code so far:

```
=QUERY(data!A1:AB,"
SELECT V,G, SUM(K), SUM(I)
WHERE K IS NOT NULL AND V >= date """&text(F3, "yyyy-MM-dd")&""" AND V <= date """&text(F4, "yyyy-MM-dd")&"""
GROUP BY V, G
ORDER BY SUM(K) DESC
LIMIT 10
LABEL SUM(K) 'SKU Sales', SUM(I) 'Units Sold'",1)
```

V is the date column, G is the Item column, K is the SKU Sales Column, I is the Units Sold Column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel silly. After typing that I didn't care about the date column, I realized my answer was to just get rid of column V in the select query and instead select column G, and group by G.

```
=QUERY(data!A1:AB,"
SELECT G, SUM(K), SUM(I)
WHERE K IS NOT NULL AND V >= date """&text(F3, "yyyy-MM-dd")&""" AND V <= date """&text(F4, "yyyy-MM-dd")&"""
GROUP BY G
ORDER BY SUM(K) DESC
LIMIT 10
LABEL SUM(K) 'SKU Sales', SUM(I) 'Units Sold'",1)
```

Comment: So, your problem is solved?